# How to customize NSS filters to match users against several attributes?

Tags: ldap, pam, nss

My context: I have a OpenSMTPD instance that uses PAM as its authentication backend. My PAM configuration use NSS to authenticate the users against a LDAP directory.

**I would like to make NSS match users either on their `uid` or their `mail` LDAP attribute.**

According to the logs I see, the default filter seems to be `(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=xxxxxx))` *where xxxxx is the user login*.

The `nslcd.conf` man page describes the `filter` parameter, but it seems there is no way to use variables with it. Plus, whatever filter I configure actually adds up with `(uid=xxxxx)` in the end *(for instance, if I set `filter passwd (foo=bar)` in the configuration file, the filter that will be used to match users will be `(&(foo=bar)(uid=xxxx))`)*.

I would like to be able to write something like `(|(uid=$login)(mail=$login))` to match users either to match users either on their `uid` or ther `mail` LDAP attribute.

Is it really not possible?
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/arthurdejong/nss-pam-ldapd/issues/45